# Converting a nummeric array to comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[participants] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 12
    )
```

I want to put it in another variable to look like this:

"9,8,12"

I tried with the code below but it does not output anything:

```
$mem = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i++)
{
    $mem.$participants[$i];
}

echo $mem;
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: You are not putting any commas in between your numbers, you would need to change this line: `$mem.$participants[$i];`, but why bother when you can use `implode()`.

Comment: if you want to concatenate them and put them into `$mem` you have to do the `=` sign first. So `$mem .= $participants[$i];`. To put comas in between you can do `$mem .= ($i > 0) ? ','.$participants[$i] : $participants[$i];` but you can use the `implode()` function to do this for you as the others indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
implode(',', $participants);
```

In your code you should have used concatenation like this:

```
$mem .= $participants[$i].',';
```

However, I would have preferred foreach like this:

```
$mem = "";
foreach ($participants as $key => $value){
    $mem .= $value.',';
}
```

If you're looping in that way, you have to get rid of the last comma when you're done:

```
$mem = rtrim($mem, ',');
```

Comment: Thanks :P that did the trick, but can you also tell me what is wrong with my own code?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
$s = implode(",", $participants);
```

The reason that your code doesn't work, is because you never do anything to `$mem`. To append strings to a string, use the `.=` operator:

```
$mem .= $participants[$i];
```

You'll see it will just glue everything together, without commas.

Answer (score 1):

to fix your code. your not assigning the result to anything

```
$mem = $mem. "," .$participants[$i];
```

or

```
$mem .=  "," . $participants[$i];
```

but implode is a better solution

also your looping method would require you to remove the comma at the start (or end)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
$mem = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i++)
{
   $mem .= ($i > 0) ? ",".$participants[$i] : $participants[$i];
}

echo $mem;
```

but as the others said, use PHP `implode()`